# Menu com margem superior

Tags: html, css

Então, estou criando uma página e quero colocar um menu, mas antes dele está criando uma margem superior. Como faço para tira-la?

```
<div class="barra">
    <p>asdaosdhs</p>
</div>
.barra{
background-color: aqua;
margin-top: 0px;
top: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O CSS vem com algumas coisas predefinidas, essa margem superior vem por conta dessas configurações.

Use isso daqui para resetar seu CSS

```css
/* Reset */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.barra {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-top: 0px;
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="barra">
  <p>Hello, world!</p>
</div>
```